# Update Change Password Page For Default And Other Groups

Tags: opencv3.0, opencart-3

I am using opencart V 3.0.3.0

I want to check if customer group id = default, then show him change password form and allow to change password. Else show table with links to other platforms on my website to change password.

Table with links to other platforms for password change is done by me and it is visible on change password page as expected.

But I not getting how to check customer group id and show form to change password ? which files from `catalog/controller` and `catalog/model` needed to change and what can be code on `password.twig`

e.g. code in `password.twig`

```
{{ if customer_group_id==1}} // 1 = default
     code to show change password form
{{ else }}
     show my created table with links to other platforms on my website.. (it is done and working as expected right now )
{{ end if }}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some search, I did it successfully.

Giving solution for others who may needed it

in catalog/controller/account/password.php added

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
       $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->customer->getGroupId();
  } elseif ($this->config->get('config_customer_group_id')) {
       $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
  }
```

after line 12 i.e.

```
  $this->load->language('account/password');
```

And in catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/password.twig

added

```
   {% if (customer_group_id=='1') %}
         // Your needed code
   {% else %}
        // another needed code
   {% endif %}
```

after

```
  <h1>{{ heading_title }}</h1>
```